# DOM child tagname

Tags: javascript, dom, tagname

I'm attempting to use javascript to traverse the children of an adult node and change properties as needed. The code hangs up on the elemtree.tagName, stating the object doesn't have that property. I've read up on DOM properties, and tagName was stated as being a property of the DOM. Why would it not be recognized?

code below:

```
   elemtree = elem.firstChild;
    while (elemtree != null) {
        if (elemtree.tagName.toLowerCase() == "img") {
            elemtree.src = img;
        }
        else {
            elemtree.display = display;
        }
        elemtree = elemtree.nextSibling;
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`elemtree.nextSibling` includes text- and comment-nodes, which have a [`nodeName`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/Node.nodeName) but no [`tagName`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/Element.tagName) property.

Solutions:

1. Use [`elem.firstElementChild`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/Element.firstElementChild) and [`elemtree.nextElementSibling`](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/DOM/Element.nextElementSibling) instead (possible browser compatibility issues).
2. Use `nodeName` instead of `tagName`.
3. Check for the existence of `tagName` prior using it:

   ```
   if (elemtree.tagName && elemtree.tagName.toLowerCase() == "img") {
   ```

Comment: Thanks. I didn't even realize I had text nodes in my html structure. It's been a long day.

Comment: Instead of looping through all nodes, you'd better use [`var imgs = elem.getElementsByTagName('img');`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.getElementsByTagName) and loop through `imgs`.

Comment: I need to change all the elements anyhow. They are display='None' and need to be display='block' or visa versa, except for the image. It just needs its src changed. It's a simple tree view I whipped up.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Rob W, that the best solution is to avoid nodes without the property to begin with, however you could also consider changing:

`if (elemtree.tagName.toLowerCase() == "img")`

to

`if (elemtree.tagName && elemtree.tagName.toLowerCase() == "img")`

That way if the property does not exist, it will not throw the error.